# Message Bus and Events - How to React?

Tags: web-services, message-queue, distributed-system

I'm designing an event-based system that involves two services, A and B.

When a user updates a resource in service A using a PUT, that service will send a notification onto a message queue. Service B reads from that queue, and then must update the state of one of its resources based on the change that occurred to the resource in A.

As I see it, there are two ways to handle this:

1. The message that service A sends contains the field of the resource that changed, and what it changed from and to. When service B consumes this message, it uses that information to determine the state of its resource.
2. The message that service A sends only contains a link to the resource that changed. When service B consumes this message, it calls that link to retrieve the current state of A's resource for its own processing.

Which method do you all find more agreeable? I lean towards #1 due to the receiver of the message not needing to possibly have out-of-band knowledge of service B (yes, it has a link but it might not have the correct headers, the correct HTTP verb, etc), and to reduce the amount of service chatter.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are viable options. Which version you choose depends on multiple things.

- How expensive is it to look up the resource? If it is expensive, then lean towards Option 1.
- How expensive is it to send the change on the queue?Option 1 sends a diff, and if that diff is large, it could become costly. Option 2 only sends a link to the resource. A third option is a to [store the diff as a resource](http://www.eaipatterns.com/StoreInLibrary.html).
- Can the system deal with multiple changes to the resource? For example, the resource could change multiple times between the time A sends the notification and system B reads the resource. If the system can deal with this, Option 2 has the opportunity to ignore some updates, potentially reducing processing. If the system cannot deal with this you must use Option 1.